# Move Focus to the next HTML.EditFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can i do in HTML.EditFor on asp.net MVC 5 that when a press enter, the focus move to the next  Html.EditFor?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Descripcion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , autofocus = "autofocus"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Descripcion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`tabindex`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp) attribute on your `inputs`. Like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , tabindex = 1 } })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , tabindex = 3} })
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Descripcion2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" , tabindex = 2 } })
```

That will allow you to change `input` focus with right order with `tab` button.

Comment: Ok, but the problem is that I have to check first that the text that I entry to EditFor starts with "P", and if it start a will change to the next EditFor. But their isn't an option to do that or yes?

Comment: Like putting a Id to the EditFor and said Focus to the next EditFor(id)

Comment: @NAMH yeah there are no option in this solution. You should use js to achive this goal. Just ask another question mark it js tag and js guys will help you

Comment: Thanks teo van kot